# Parse HTML by breaklines using HTML AgilityPack

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a specific HTML string so that i can extract a set of lines broken up by `<br/>` break lines. The input HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="PlainText">
  DATE: 2013-10-28 20:00:43 -0500 <br/>
  Item 1: Text1 <br/>
  Item 1: Text1 <br/>
  Item 1: Text1 <br/>
  Item 1: Text1 <br/>
  <br/> //Notice this has two break lines, i would like to stop after seeing two consecutive break lines.
</div>
```

With this div in a larger html document,  i was able to get the `HTML ChildNodes`

```
List<HtmlNode> nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                                    .Descendants("div")
                                    .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                                            x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("PlainText")).ToList();
```

I am not entirely sure where to go from here, i would like to read all the text until i see two breaklines and stop ?

**EDIT**

I looked at the childNodes `nodes` in Visual Studio runtime inspector and noticed there actually isn't two consectuive `<br/>` lines but a single break line and a `#text` tag with its innerHTMl being `\n` a new line character.

[image]

Comment: Really? I see two br tags using your same example that you posted

Comment: The input HTML has two br tags but as you can see from the screenshot and what i got from inspecting while debugging what `nodes` returns, there is a `#text` tag in between them with an InnerHtml that reads just a newline character.

Comment: Do you care about the newline? Your question only states about br tags.  If newlines are a problem you can just use a string trim on it

Comment: no i don't care about the newline, i thought i would mention it since technically it isn't two `br` tags right after each other but a newline in between them

Comment: HtmlAgility pack treats newlines as part of the text field (since newlines are just text, they aren't a tag), so they really make no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var x = ReadTillTwoBr(GetDivClass()).ToList();
}

public HtmlNode GetDivClass()
{
    var html = @"<html><div class=""PlainText"">
            DATE: 2013-10-28 20:00:43 -0500 <br/>
            Item 1: Text1 <br/>
            Item 1: Text1 <br/>
            Item 1: Text1 <br/>
            Item 1: Text1 <br/>
            <br   /> //Notice this has two break lines, i would like to stop after seeing two consecutive break lines.
            Item 3
        </div></html>";
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    return doc.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("div").First(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                                                x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("PlainText"));

}

public IEnumerable<string> ReadTillTwoBr(HtmlNode node)
{
    var nonEmptyNodes =
        node.ChildNodes.Except(node.ChildNodes.Where(f => f.Name == "#text" && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.InnerHtml)))
            .ToList();

    foreach (var n in nonEmptyNodes)
    {
        if (IsBr(n) && IsBr(n.NextSibling))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        if (n.Name == "#text")
        {
            yield return n.InnerText.Trim();
        }
    }
}

public bool IsBr(HtmlNode n)
{
    return n != null && n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element && n.Name == "br";
}
```

Which returns

[image]

Notice how it didn't return the comment after the two br's

EDIT:

I removed empty `#text` values since when you have a newline between the last two `br` tags you actually get a `#text` tag with newlines. I think this is where the newline confusion lay.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted but could i use some of the same ideas here for checking an Element `#text` with only a `\n` newline character

Comment: There, I updated it so that it reads all #text until two consecutive br/ tags are found.

Comment: @Warz does this help? Or did I misunderstand what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes it helps, i am just running my tests now to see if the text tags as you mention are negligible and are ignored when your `isBr` runs. Thanks by the way

Comment: I keep getting nothing back and i have modified the script a few times. The yield break never happens and returns all child nodes back

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40332/discussion-between-warz-and-devshorts)

Comment: I defined an explict `\n` checker. `  public static bool IsNewLine(HtmlNode n)
        {
            return n != null && n.InnerHtml == "\n";
        }`

Comment: @Warz, I updated the answer to work with newline seperated line break tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath `//div[@class='PlainText']` to get required div nodes. Also you can check next sibling node when taking child nodes from div:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("index.html");
Func<HtmlNode, bool> notTwoBrakes = 
    n => (n.Name != "br" || n.NextSibling != null && n.NextSibling.Name != "br");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='PlainText']")
               .Select(div => div.ChildNodes.TakeWhile(notTwoBrakes));
```

I don't use inline lambda just for readability. Condition works like this:

- Check if next node is null, if it's null, then take current node
- Check if next node is `br` node, if not - take current node
- Check if current node is `br` node, if not - take current node
- Otherwise stop taking child nodes

Result:

[image]

Comment: I still get everything after the second `br` and `#text` back with your `notTwoBrakes` check ?

Comment: @Warz just verified, everything works fine. Maybe you have some other conditions to stop reading data. My query stops reading nodes in each div after double break found. You can see it in debugger screenshot